# how to convert list to dict of index and data in one line(for use in lambda)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want to convert to following format

```
{0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d' }
```

Can somebody tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need a dict? You say "for use in lambda", but I don't see why the dict would be more useful in a lambda than the list would be.

Comment: I just want to use for no absolute reason..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dict(enumerate(a))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> dict(enumerate(a))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Learning about `dict` comprehension can be useful too:

```
>>>a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>>{k:v for k,v in enumerate(a)}
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
```